# DLL load failed _multiarray_unmath when importing numpy

Tags: numpy

I installed Numpy v. 1.18.4 and Python 3.8. These are the latest as of 5/2020 I think. I get the error:

```
Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\Users\SScott1\.conda\envs\cartoenv7_3_8\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.18.4"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.
```

Is there a place I can report this? How do I resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you launch VS Code outside of Anaconda Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

This question already has a few answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63949451/riginal-error-was-dll-load-failed-while-importing-multiarray-umath) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68931913/importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-multiarray-umath). Adding this to the environment path worked for me:

C:\Users\ <username> \Anaconda3\Library\bin