# riginal error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath

Tags: python

i got a something weird situation with import packages.

when i use numpy on Jupyter notebook, it's fine and my all source codes are run without problem

but if i use numpy on Visual Studio Code i got a something error.

```
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\Users\Mohw-IN\anaconda3\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.18.5"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module cannot be used
다.
```

and i found something weird.

```
import os
print("PYTHONPATH:", os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'))
---------------
PYTHONPATH: None
```

how can i do for use numpy in vscode?

Answer (score 9):

It appears to be some issue related to path variable. This issue has been discussed on below github link.

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14770

To solve this, we need to add C:\Users<username>\Anaconda3\Library\bin" in your PATH user variable. Please replace "username" with actual value.

Now VS Code should work fine.

Comment: This solved the issue. I think running `conda activate <env>` would have also done the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I don't even know what PATH is but i found an easier way to solve the problem

Install Anaconda

Open VScode from anaconda navigator

Done :)
You should be able to use Numpy now

---

If i open VScode from the desktop shortcut i still have the same problem

I don't now "why" it happens but i don't really care

hope this is usefull

Comment: `$PATH` (or `%PATH%` or the like) means 'where we look for things we want to run'.  Opening VScode from anaconda opens it in an 'environment' where everything is set up to point at anaconda's libraries and programs (and is indeed the easiest way to fire them up together).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a mismatch between the version of Numpy and Pandas (I had just upgraded to v1.4). Fix by upgrading numpy to sync it with Pandas:

In Anaconda/Miniconda:

```
conda update numpy
```

Or with pip:

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

Or this (very heavy-handed) approach which upgrades all packages:

```
conda install --update-all numpy
```

Answer (score -2):

Open Anaconda and Launch Visual Studio. Now run the program.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).